# Access the variable updated in CoroutinScope in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I have globally declared variables and updated the value inside the coroutinScope. when I call the value outside the coroutinScope its value does not update. How I can access the value updated inside coroutinScop in outside. here is the example.  after I get some data from endpoint through HTTP client fuel I need to update the variables v1 and v2.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


var v1 = 0
var v2 = 0



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val datalink1 = "abcdefj.json"


    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch() {

    val abcd = Fuel.get(datalink1t).awaitString()

    if(abcd.equals("c")){
    v1++
    }

    else if(abcd.equals("d")){
    v2++
    }
```

I want to access v1 and v2 updated inside coroutinscope globally so that I can use the in other activity or adapter class. but I get only the initial value 0. how I could update that as globally. I am new to kotlin or coroutine please help.

or look at the following attached code simple example with coroutinScope block inside onCreate method of mainActivity kotlin.  I want to update globally the value of k within the coroutinscope . I want to achieve the update of value of k being updated in coroutinscope but accessing this update outside. but I I am getting the initial value. anyone help how to obtain this simple question,
please. I want the value of k 4 after updated in coroutinscope and access out of the coroutinscope . thanks

[image]

Comment: There's no reason these shouldn't be getting updated globally. How are you verifying that they are not?

Comment: Probably an inter-thread visibility issue, marking those two `var`s `@Volatile` should make the changes in the IO coroutines visible to other threads.

Comment: to make clear the value of v1 and v2 normally updated inside coroutinscope after HTTP call Fuel.get(datalink1t).awaitString() and that is okay. but outside coroutinscope the value of v1 and v2 is still zero the initial value. how to use voltile can you explain a little more  @George Leung

Comment: @Tenfour04  can you see at my updated code. i just want to show that it does not work and it is not getting updated

Comment: You’re logging the value immediately after launching the coroutine, so the coroutine hasn’t even had a chance to get started yet by the time you log it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the same is true for the big file. I tried to log in other activity trying to get the updated value in coroutinscope in other functions and classes. but it giving me the same initially declared zero value outside the coroutin scope everywhere in main activity class or other activity function and classes.

Comment: Are you waiting sufficient time to be sure the coroutine has completed its work before you check the values?

Comment: @Tenfour04  Yes I did. and I could not figure out what the problem. thanks for your comment by the way

Comment: Maybe you could share an example of that code. (And please paste text, not pictures.) The code you show above makes sense. You can see that you are logging from outside the coroutine before the coroutine finishes and logs from within. But you should probably make the properties volatile or choose a single thread from which to access them. In a coroutine, you could always wrap uses of the properties with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { }` to make sure they are always accessed only from the main thread, like most of your non-coroutine is called on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229123/discussion-between-sirway-and-tenfour04).

Answer (score 2):

A coroutine runs your code inside the block ansynchronously. You can see from your logs that the logging outside of the coroutine is called before the logging inside it. That is why you only see the initial value.

If you want to use the updated value, you just have to get it after a little delay. It is also set globally by then.